# lwIP: How to avoid "Memory Error (ERR_MEM) " in applications which needs continously Connection-Disconnection process?

Tags: tcp, stm32, ethernet, freertos, lwip

I have an embedded TCP Client application which using lwIP TCP/IP stack and raw API in the local network. The device continuously polls the server devices in every 2 secs. The scenario is like in below:

- The client connects to the server device.
- It sends a query.
- It receives a response from the server.
- It parses and processing data.
- The client closes the connection to connect another server device with a different IP.
- Goes back to the first step and state machine continuously runs in that scenario.

After some time (300 polling) when I call *tcp_connect* function, it returns *ERR_MEM* memory error. After that, I am not able to connect server devices. It is like my application is getting all memory over after continuously connection-disconnection process because it always happens after a certain number of a poll.

I analyzed the sending/receiving frames in Wireshark and connection/disconnection process works as expected. In 3rd party TCP Server software, I checked whether the disconnection process works correctly or not.

I need some recommendations to avoid memory error in that scenario.

Best Regards

```c
struct tcp_pcb *pxPCBMaster;
struct sTCPMasterClient sTCPMasterClient;

/*
* This function continously runs in super loop.
* It connects and disconnects successfully but after some time
* tcp_connect function returns ERR_MEM.
*/

void vTCPSocketTestFunc (void)
{
   pxPCBMaster = tcp_new(); 

   ip_addr_t xDestIPAddress;

   IP4_ADDR (&xDestIPAddress, 192, 168, 10, 7);

   // Connect to test server
   err_t eConnStatus = tcp_connect (pxPCBMaster, 
                                   &xDestIPAddress, 
                                   80, 
                                   prveMBTCPMPortConnectionCallback);
   if (eConnStatus != ERR_OK)
   {
       printf("DEBUG_MBTCPM_PORT: TCP Connection Error Occured\n");
       printf("DEBUG_MBTCPM_PORT: Exception Code: %d\n", eConnStatus);
   }

   else
   {
      printf("DEBUG_MBTCPM_PORT: TCP Connection is successful\n");

      // Refresh Ethernet Driver and Add 2 secs Delay
      for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
      {
         ethernetif_input(&tcpNetif);
         HAL_Delay (10);
      }

      if (sTCPMasterClient != NULL)
      {
         mem_free(sTCPMasterClient );
      }

      // Close connection
      tcp_close(pxPCBMaster);

      // Aborts the connection by sending a RST (reset) segment to the remote 
      // host. The pcb is deallocated
      tcp_abort(pxPCBMaster);

      // Refresh Ethernet Driver and Add 2 secs Delay
      for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
      {
         ethernetif_input(&tcpNetif);
         HAL_Delay (10);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak or memory fragmentation issue.

Comment: Yes but I do not know how it occurs because when we call tcp_close and tcp_abort functions, created tcb object is freed.

Comment: You said you also process data during each connection. If that involves dynamic memory allocation it could also cause an issue. Any allocations could cause this, not just those related strictly to TCP connection.

Comment: I created the test code which is continuously connecting to the server device and disconnecting without sending/receiving and processing any data. The result is the same that's why I am sure that it is not related to the processing data.

Comment: Unless there's a specific reason not to, you should set `sTCPMasterClient` to `NULL` after freeing it.